# Ranger Knox Plugin error

Tags: apache-ranger, apache-knox

I am trying to enable Ranger Knox plugin. I created a service called 'knoxdev', test connection is successful. But still I am not able to see service 'knoxdev' in audit->plugin tab. I have hdfs plugin enabled too and service created for same as 'hadoopdev'. I am able to see 'hadoodev' in audit->plugin tab but not 'knoxdev'.

Then I checked gateway.log and gateway-audit.log. I can see response code as 200.

Then I checked ranger_admin.log, and there I find this error:

> ERROR org.apache.ranger.plugin.util.PasswordUtils
>   (PasswordUtils.java:130) - Unable to decrypt password due to error
>   javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple
>   of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher

Can anyone help?